# How to get an itinerary from a record locator

Tags: air-travel

If I have a record locator (PNR?) the 6-character code that passengers get, how can I get the details of the corresponding itinerary? Is there some (possibly paid) service on the web that can do this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you’re asking? You can of course check a specific flight itinerary easily enough, but I’m doubtful there’s anything out there that would give an ordinary person details of a 3rd party’s itinerary (if that is indeed what you’re looking for).

Comment: I'm not looking to look at someone else's itinerary - just mine. It is pretty complex, involves code-share partners so the airline I'm flying on does not recognize the record locator, the travel agent is in another country and is not picking up the phone etc. etc. Long story. So I was just wondering if there was some kind of online service where I could enter the PNR and get back the itinerary.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to look up information about a reservation if you have the PNR (a.k.a. record locator, booking reference, confirmation code, reservation number, etc.) or ticket number plus the name of the passenger. Most major airlines provide an online form where you can do this, e.g. [ANA](https://www.ana.co.jp/en/us/search/int/mybooking.html), [Icelandair](https://www.icelandair.com/support/pre-flight/manage-booking/), [Air Canada](https://www.aircanada.com/us/en/aco/home.html#/home:mngBook). The only catch is that you must use a locator which the airline's system understands, which you may not be in possession of if you booked, for example, through a partner airline.

Depending on where the ticket was booked, it may also be possible to look up the information from a GDS or travel agent website. Expedia lets you look up an itinerary with the itinerary number and the email address associated with the reservation. For Travelport there is [ViewTrip](https://www.viewtrip.com/), which lets you do a look up with a last name.

For Sabre there is [Virtually There](https://www.virtuallythere.com/) and for Amadeus there is [CheckMyTrip](https://www.checkmytrip.com/), but those require setting up a separate account and I have not used either in over a decade.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try them all. I don't know which underlying reservation system was used, so I don't know which of these will work, or I have to find some other 4th service etc. I guess I was hoping that there might be some type of universal online service where, if I enter a PNR (and last name?) it might spit out the full itinerary, regardless of where the ticket came from or which reservation system was used, etc.

Comment: @KevinMulligan If you know you will be on a particular flight operated by a particular airline, that airline should be able to look you up and give you whichever PNR they have for you. Sometimes, they may have access to identifiers used by their partners as well, and sometimes, the airline uses the same identifier as its preferred GDS. There's no central database AFAIK; you have to check with each vendor, much like you can't ask Walmart if they can find your Amazon order number for you.

Answer (score -1):

I sure hope there would not be any, and, as "the bad guys" presumably already would know,for reference:

https://www.pcmag.com/news/350685/luggage-tag-code-unlocks-flights-flyer-miles-your-identity

I believe that exposing possible issues, [i.e. in this case big thanks to pcmag] and me just trying to help to spread out the messgae, may speed up to get fixes done, and, to repeat, the bad guys already presumably know.

So, there is nothing you can do about the tags attached to your luggage between the luggage drop and the arrival belt, but, better remove them after the belt [ BUT KEEP ALSO THE LUGAGGE TAGS AVAILABLE until you are out of the airport, since you may need them when passing the customs and/or exiting the airport, as in some places, even on domestic flights, they cross-check your luggage tag and the "copy" you have to avoid luggage thefts. Also, consider where you throw away your "boarding passes" or other documents where traceable information is included. It is not only about your itinerary, but you might risk also more personal information revealed!